# Reversing array but only one element is returning

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to reverse an array and I think the for loop is wrong but everyone I've shown it to doesn't see a problem.

```
#include <iostream>

void reverse() {
  int temp;
  const int size = 9;
  int arr[size] = {1, 4, 10, 16, 34, 7, 8, 9, 11};
  for (int i=0; i <size-1; i++){
    for (int j=size-1; j>=0; j--){
      arr[j]= temp;
      arr[i] = temp;
    }
  }
  for(int x= 0; x<size; x++){
    std::cout<<arr[x]<< " ";
  }
}

int main () {

  reverse();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger and examine how the variables change in each step.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Where is `temp` assigned (or, even, initialized)?

Comment: Think about your algorithm. Why do you have two loops, one inside the other? What does that achieve? You only need one loop to reverse a sequence.

Comment: You need to find some better collaborators if no-one you've shown this to can find a problem.

Comment: Here's the algorithm you need. Loop through the array but only go half way. Swap each element with the corresponding element at the other end of the array, so first array element is swapped with last array element, second array element is swapped with second last array element etc. It's common sense really. You're probably thinking to much about C++, first you need to think in *general terms* how to do something, then you need to think how to translate that into C++.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use an algorithm of the std, namely `std::reverse`. You don't have to invent an algorithm, that reverts an array.

Thus your code is reduced to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

void reverse() {
    std::array<int, 9> arr{1, 4, 10, 16, 34, 7, 8, 9, 11};
    std::reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    for (const auto& item : arr) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    reverse();
    return 0;
}
```

Choosing proper container and algorithm form the standard library will significantly enhance the quality (in terms of bugs, readability, ...) and speed up you development. Furthermore, in most cases the runtime of your program will be shorter as well.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning std::reverse

Answer (score 1):

This would be faster. You just traverse half of the array and switch the elements don't do n² traversion, this is definitely not needed here.

```
void reverse() {
  const int size = 9;
  int arr[size] = {1, 4, 10, 16, 34, 7, 8, 9, 11};

  int back = size - 1;
  int temp;
  for( int i = 0; i < size / 2; ++i)
  {
     temp = arr[i];
     arr[i] = arr[back];
     arr[back--] = temp;
  }
  for( auto n : arr )
    std::cout << n << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
```

}

to your code:

```
void reverse() {
  int temp;
  const int size = 9;
  int arr[size] = {1, 4, 10, 16, 34, 7, 8, 9, 11};
  for (int i=0; i <size-1; i++){
    for (int j=size-1; j>=0; j--){ // here every element is set to 
    // temp, but temp isn initialized so they are set to a random value. 
    // Try setting temp to 0 and look what happens your whole array should 
    // become 0.
      arr[j]= temp; 
      arr[i] = temp;
    }
  }
  for(int x= 0; x<size; x++){
    std::cout<<arr[x]<< " ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include<iostream> 
    using namespace std;
    void reverse() {
      int temp;
      const int size = 9;
      int arr[size] = {1, 4, 10, 16, 34, 7, 8, 9, 11};
      for (int i=0, j =size-1; i <j ; i++, j--)
      {
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] =  arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
      }
      for(int x= 0; x<size; x++){
        std::cout<<arr[x]<< " ";
      }
    }

    int main () {

      reverse();
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'temp' in your code is not initialised.

// I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
temp = arr[i];
arr[i] = arr[j];
arr[j] = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

check this one to reverse ur array..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse() {
  int temp;
  const int size = 9;
  int arr[size] = {1, 4, 10, 16, 34, 7, 8, 9, 11};
  for (int i=8; i>=0; i--){


//   cout<<arr[i]<< " ";
   std::cout<<arr[i]<< " ";
  }

}

int main () {

  reverse();
  return 0;
}
```

[image]